# Why does fillPoly fill my polygon in the wrong color?

Tags: python, opencv

I create a zero mask with the size of 650x475. When I fill it with the `fillPoly` function (third parameter 255 for white), my window shows a blue color instead of white

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    with mss.mss() as sct:
        monitor = {"top": 360, "left": 810, "width": 650, "height": 475}
        output = "sct-{top}x{left}_{width}x{height}.png".format(**monitor)
        # Grab the data
        sct_img = np.array(sct.grab(monitor))
        shap = sct_img.shape



        while 2>1:

            mask = np.zeros_like(sct_img)
            a3 = np.array([[[590, 12], [650, 12], [650, 460], [590, 460]]], dtype=np.int32)
            cv2.fillPoly(mask, a3, 255)

            cv2.imshow("OPENCV/NUMPY normal", mask)

            if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
                cv2.destroyAllWindows()
                break
```

[image: Here my windows]

Why does it show it in blue?

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV read color images as Blue, Green, Red (BGR) form. [source](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/df2/tutorial_py_basic_ops.html)

Therefore when you set `255` = `[255, 0, 0]` which means display blue, but don't display green and red.

To set the color as white:

```py
cv2.fillPoly(mask, a3, [255, 255, 255])
```